# How do i hide my submit button until my Form is validated

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am currently doing a school project and once again, I have another question to ask! I would like to create a function that prevents my submit button from working unless the value in my "Topic" and "Question" is filled.

What I want to try doing, is to make my Submit button become `display: none;` if my "topic" and "Question" field is empty.

I have tried using a `if (data != 0)` or a `.strLength` extension. However, I am not really sure of how it should work.

Any help will be appreciated

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="TestingTrueQuestionStylesheet.css">

    <script>
      function submitAnswer(){

      var data = document.getElementById("Question").value;
      var topicName = document.getElementById("TopicName").value;


      localStorage.newdata = data;
      localStorage.topicName = topicName;



      }

    </script>
  </head>


  <body>
      <form>
        <fieldset>
              <input placeholder="Topic" id="TopicName" required type="text"></input>
              <br/>
              <textarea placeholder="Question" id="Question" required rows="30" cols="100"></textarea>
              <br/>

              <input type="submit" onclick="submitAnswer()" id="SubmitButton" required ></input>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have a look at z666zz666z's answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/932653/how-to-prevent-buttons-from-submitting-forms?rq=1

Comment: Done hide the button but set its property to disabled i.e. <input type-'submit' disabled='disabled'> then the validation, if it passes can the reset the disabled attribute i.e. document.getElementById('SubmitButton').disabled = '';

Comment: A disabled button could be a very confusing UX for the users since they would not be sure how to make it enabled (unless you will leave visual cues on what fields are mandatory in your form). Maybe a solution for you would be allowing users to click submit button but if fields are missing you will render a good intuitive warning/error message on a screen prompting users to type missing information.

Comment: @Abaddon666 OP is probably not using jquery..

Comment: @Anirudha must have misread the question. thought he was. Thanks for ponting out!

Comment: @anvk I just realized that too! Is there any way to do that? I am unsure of how to go about doing it

Answer (score 0):

You should not hide but disable the button.A better solution would be to let user submit the form and then check the forms validity using the `checkValidity` function

```
function submitAnswer(){
    var f = document.forms["myform"];//get hold of the form
    if(f.checkValidity()){
         // form is valid
    }
    else{
         //form is invalid
    }
```

Also you will have to name the form

```
 <form name="myform">
```

---

If you want to disable the button you will have to add `onkeyup` event handler on each of your form elements and call below function

```
var f=document.forms['myform'];
var sbmtBtn=document.getElementById('SubmitButton');
function checkFormsValidity(){
        if(f.checkValidity()){
             sbmtBtn.disabled=false;
        }
        else{
             sbmtBtn.disabled=true;
        }
}
```

Your html will look like

```
<form name='myform'>
..
<input onkeyup='checkFormsValidity()'..
<textarea onkeyup='checkFormsValidity()'..
```

[disabled button demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jAkwKg)

Comment: May i know if it is possible for the Question field to only work if a certain number of words are inputted! For example, they cant click submit unless 50 words are inside

Comment: @JustinSoh you can use the `minlength=50` attribute for that input..Its an html5 feature... refer [this](http://www.wufoo.com/html5/attributes/18-minlength.html)